# Pegar parte do conteúdo html armazenado em uma variável

Tags: php, html

Tenho um problema que não consegui achar uma solução na net.

Simples quero pegar apenas o segundo `<p>` do texto, da `div` no caso, é + - assim:

```
<div id='central'>
<p>O Primeiro conteudo</p>
<h1>O Primeiro n sei oq</h1>
<p>Batatinha quando nasce</p>
<p>Cabooo</p>
</div>
```

No caso quero pegar o conteúdo dentro do segundo `<p>`
isto em PHP é claro que o  conteúdo estaria em uma string pra poder ser manipulada.

```
$string = '   <div id="central">
    <p>O Primeiro conteudo</p>
    <h1>O Primeiro n sei oq</h1>
    <p>Batatinha quando nasce</p>
    <p>Cabooo</p>
    </div>';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não faz muito sentido o que você quer fazer da forma como está fazendo, mas achei esta função [**neste site**](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/get-a-html-tag-and-store-in-a-php-variable/5558/2), que atende ao que você está querendo fazer:

```
function get_tag($txt,$tag){
    $offset = 0;
    $start_tag = "<".$tag;
    $end_tag = "</".$tag.">";
    $arr = array();
    do{
        $pos = strpos($txt,$start_tag,$offset); 
        if($pos){
            $str_pos = strpos($txt,">",$pos)+1;
            $end_pos = strpos($txt,$end_tag,$str_pos);  
            $len = $end_pos - $str_pos;
            $f_text = substr($txt,$str_pos,$len);


    $arr[] = $f_text;
        $offset = $end_pos;
    }
}while($pos);
return $arr;
```

}

```
$txt = '<div id="central">
<p>O Primeiro conteudo</p>
<h1>O Primeiro n sei oq</h1>
<p>Batatinha quando nasce</p>
<p>Cabooo</p>
</div>';
$arr = get_tag($txt, "p");

echo $arr[1];
```

No caso, o código vai pegar todo o conteúdo que achar entre a abertura e fechamento da tag informada. Como você quer apenas da segunda, usei o `$arr[1]`.

Veja funcionando no [**IDEONE**](http://ideone.com/GP7HoO).

Comment: é pra pegar informação de um streming

Comment: @LeandroFerreira na pergunta, você diz que quer pegar o texto dentro da tag `p`, em um códígo que está em uma variavel no php.  A resposta atende a dúvida, mas o que é streming?

Comment: Streaming é tipo um sistema de comunicação de navegador ele tem varias informações como frequência quem está comunicando essas coisas - um exemplo de straming http://158.69.17.192:9992 dai tem umas paginas desse tipo q eu tenho q pegar a informação dai ele retorna uma string só com com um monte de 'p' e eu quero pegar só a segunda

Comment: @LeandroFerreira ah sim, uma vez que você já está com a variável preenchida com o conteudo, conforme você mostrou no código, essa função irá atender perfeitamente. Alias, não só pra tag `p`, mas você pode usá-la para pegar o conteudo de qualquer tag. Só tome cuidado com tags internas iguais(tipo div dentro de div), porque neste caso a função pode apresentar um comportamento não esperado.

Comment: Blz, Vlw  ajudou bastante.

Answer (score 0):

O problema para esse caso pode ser facilmente resolvido utilizando expressões regulares.
Apenas necessitaria realizar um pequena alteração do alvo. adicionando uma `class=""` na tag desejada.

```
<div id='central'>
    <p>O Primeiro conteudo</p>
    <h1>O Primeiro n sei oq</h1>
    <p class="tag-alvo">Batatinha quando nasce</p>
    <p>Cabooo</p>
</div>
```

a regex ficaria assim: `<(?:(p)).*tag-alvo.*?>(.*)<\/\1>`

segue exemplo: https://regex101.com/r/pRRqtE/1

No php ficará assim:

```
$alvo = '<div id="central">
<p>O Primeiro conteudo</p>
<h1>O Primeiro n sei oq</h1>
<p class="tag-alvo">Batatinha quando nasce</p>
<p>Cabooo</p>
</div>';

$pattern = "~<(?:(p)).*tag-alvo.*?>(.*)<\/\\1>~";

$resultado = preg_match_all($pattern, $alvo, $matches);

if ($resultado >= 1) {
    print "achou";
    var_dump($matches);

} else if ($resultado === 0) {
    print "não achou".PHP_EOL;
    var_dump($matches);

} else if ($resultado === false) {
    print "ocorreu um erro";
}
```

repare que no PHP antes do `\1` na regex tive que adicionar mais uma `\`, segue citação para explicar o motivo:

> Um caractere que caso contrário será interpretado como uma construção de linguagem sem escape deve ser interpretada literalmente. Por exemplo, uma chave ({) começa a definição de um quantificador, mas uma barra invertida seguida por uma chave ({) indica que o mecanismo de expressão regular deve corresponder a chave. Da mesma forma, uma barra invertida marca o início de uma construção de linguagem de escape, mas duas barras invertidas (\) indica que o mecanismo de expressão regular deve corresponder a barra invertida.

Segue link com texto completo sobre a citação: 
 - [Escapes de caracteres em expressões regulares](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/4edbef7e(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

A melhor forma de se tratar HTML com PHP é utilizar a classe [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domdocument.php):

```
$string = '   <div id="central">
    <p>O Primeiro conteudo</p>
    <h1>O Primeiro n sei oq</h1>
    <p>Batatinha quando nasce</p>
    <p>Cabooo</p>
    </div>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($string);

$div = $dom->getElementById("central");
$ps = $div->getElementsByTagName("p");

echo $ps[1]->nodeValue;
```

> Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/Itzo).

A saída será:

```
Batatinha quando nasce
```

Quanto utilizar regex em HTML, é interessante ler esta [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1452488).

Answer (score -2):

A pergunta ficou bastante confusa, mas vou tentar te ajudar, se é que entendi.

O que tem como você fazer é criar uma variável e manipular ela, colocando o texto que você quiser, por exemplo *batatinha quando nasce*, e depois inserir ela no código de varias formas, uma delas seria a seguinte:

(lembrando que PHP, diferente do HTML eh uma linguagem que executa no servidor, você precisa ter instalado algum servidor como o "wamp server", ter ele ativo e o arquivo `.php` deve ser executado no servidor)

```
<?php
    $string ="Batatinha quando nasce";
?>
    <div id="central">
    <p>O Primeiro conteudo</p>
    <h1>O Primeiro n sei oq</h1>
<?php
    echo'<p>'.'$string'.'</p>';
?>
    <p>Cabooo</p>
    </div>';
```

Comment: Não sei explicar direito... Eu quero pegar o conteudo q está dentro dela, não colocar

Comment: Acredito que no caso basta copiar entao o conteudo para uma string. Como o conteudo nao eh uma variavel e nao vai mudar, e quem tem o controle da pagina web que esta sendo criada eh voce, como o conteudo nao eh dinamico basta pegar `Batatinha quando nasce` e jogar dentro da string direto, no codigo php:<?php $string = "Batatinha quando nasce";?>

Comment: Pelo que entendi(a pergunta não está nada clara), ele quer pegar o texto entre a tag `p`, e não inserir.

Comment: O que ele perguntou parece ter sido o oposto do que foi respondido....